# HTML form - PGP Encrypt file uploads from stream

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, encryption

I try to develop a web upload form, till now server is Apache and PHP.

The requirements are:

- File uploads have to be PGP encrypted
- The original file MUST NOT be temporary stored as file on the server (at no time)
- Also large files (~1GB) have to be supported
- Cross platform support (Windows, Linux, Mac, iOS, Android, ...)

So the possibilities to encrypt the file would be:

- Client side - Javascript
- Client side - ?
- Server side - directly from input stream

I tried to use [OpenPGP.js](https://openpgpjs.org), but this will not support large files. Also Edge and older Browsers are not supported.

To my knowledge, PHP and Java (Tomcat, Jetty) store file uploads in temp directory.

Java Applets and similar solutions require installation of additional software at client side.

So in my opinion the only working solution could be server side.

But how could this look like?

---

Edit:

What if I read the file chunked with JS and sending parts as POST request (not as file) and putting the parts together server side?
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-example-slicingfiles

- Is $_POST also stored as temp file or in memory?
- Is it possible to PGP encrypt the file in parts?
- How to read the file to not loose information (binary / text) and what about the encoding of the file?

Comment: what do you have done so far ?

Comment: The only solution is clientside. If you upload a file to a server, it will be saved as temporary file, this cannot be changed.

Comment: Till now I tested the javascript solution, but as mentioned large files could not be encrypted. After some brainstorming this wouldn't be possible using PHP. But for the file encryption it's not important to use PHP. If this is possible in another language it would be great. Also it would be conceivable to use a mod for apache or i.e. some customizing in Jetty.